# Err doesn't accept argument that has been converted "to_string"

Tags: rust

I am trying to return an error with a formatted message.

```
let msg = format!("wrong num of dimensions: {}", dimensions.len()).to_string();
return Err(msg);
```

`dimensions` is a `Vec<i32>` that is supposed to have a length of 3. If it doesn't, I want to raise this error. However, I am getting this compiler error:

```
   Compiling advent02 v0.1.0 (file:///home/garrett/notes/rust/advent/advent02)
src/main.rs:19:24: 19:27 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&str`,
    found `collections::string::String`
(expected &-ptr,
    found struct `collections::string::String`) [E0308]
src/main.rs:19             return Err(msg);
                                  ^~~
```

It looks to me like it wants an `&str` type when I am giving it a `String` type. I have tried to do this from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23975391/how-to-convert-string-into-static-str) but get borrow errors because the returned string borrow goes out of scope.

I don't understand because [this page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/error-handling.html) is littered with examples that do `Err(err.to_string())`, and *they* don't seem to have a problem.

Comment: It would be best if you can provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Then people trying to answer it just have to edit your code to get it to compile instead of creating totally new code from scratch.

Comment: will do in the future, thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete Rust program that shows the behavior you wanted:

```
fn test() -> Result<u32, String> {
    let msg = format!("Error code {}.", 123).to_string();
    return Err(msg);
}

fn main() {
    match test() {
        Ok(num) => println!("Okay: {}", num),
        Err(msg) => println!("Error: {}", msg),
    };
}
```

This compiles without warnings or errors and prints "Error: Error code 123." when run.

The important thing here is to declare the return type of the function that is returning the error code.  If you don't declare the return type, then the Rust compiler apparently does a bad job of figuring out what the return type should be, and you get errors (but the errors I get from rustc 1.5.0 are different from yours).  This might actually be a bug in the Rust compiler; you could report this to the developers of the language and see what they have to say.

The `Err` thing that you used is just a type constructor for [std::result::Result](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/).  So the return type of the function should be some type of `Result`.

Comment: I should have posted the whole code. Of course this was my fault for declaring the return type as `Result<i32, &'static str>` (I feel pretty dumb typing that now). I'm so new to polymorphism that I don't think I am reading the right code to find where something goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The return type of your function is `Result<T, &str>`, that's why the compiler is complaining. You create a `String` instance, take a reference to it and try to return. When the function returns, the `String` instance is freed and your returned reference would be invalid (a dangling pointer).

I'd change the signature of the function to return a `Result<T, String>`. That way, you move the string out of the function without freeing it.

Comment: That was totally it! Thanks a lot. I'm accepting the other answer because it has a better example (someting I should have done in the first place...)