# Static lifetime for a temporary variable?

Tags: rust

I have the following function:

```rust
fn load_data() -> Result<MyData> {
    // ...
    Ok(my_data)
}
```

I want to call this function only once during the execution of my program and save the result in a `static` variable.
It'd be nice if the result is of type `Option<MyData>`, so the consumer just needs to check if the data is there or not, regardless of the reason of why it's not there.

I have came up with the following:

```rust
lazy_static! {
    static ref DATA: Option<&'static MyData> = load_data().ok().as_ref();
}
```

However, that line fails:

```
35 |     static ref DATA: Option<&'static MyData> = load_data().ok().as_ref();
   |                                                ----------------^^^^^^^^^
   |                                                |               returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
   |                                                |
   |                                                |
   |                                                temporary value created here
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want or am I conceptually wrong?

Comment: If that doesn't bother you, you can leak it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30527289/4498831

Comment: Why not just `lazy_static! {    static ref DATA: Option<MyData> = load_data().ok(); }` ?