# concat string using format!() and return to &'static str

Tags: rust

I'll get error when compiled: `'returns value referencing data owned by the current function'`

here's the code:

```
fn return_static_str(a: &'static str, b: &'static str) -> &'static str {
    format!("{} {}", a,b).as_str()
}

fn main() {
    let s = return_static_str("Hello ", "World!");
}
```

using return `as_ref()` get same issue.

Comment: Why not just return a String?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return local String as a slice (&str)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428227/return-local-string-as-a-slice-str)

Comment: This is impossible. The string you're creating is owned by the `return_static_str` function, so you can't return a reference to it. Return a `String` instead.

Comment: Maybe also [How to convert a String into a &'static str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23975391/how-to-convert-a-string-into-a-static-str)

Comment: You might be able to use [`concat!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.concat.html) instead if this is meant for use with literals.

Comment: @Lucretiel you can also make this a duplicate of more appropriate questions (I've added one)