# rust str slice from string

Tags: string, rust, match, slice

> "A slice is a kind of reference, so it does not have ownership."

The following code is simplified. It needs to return a slice using a `match`. All but one match arm return a string slice. One arm needs to add single quotations around a slice, thus we turn to using `format!` that returns `String`. The String must then convert to `&str`.

The error shows that the resulting slice is referenced by the temporary String in the match arm.

```
11 |     ret
   |     ^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

The simplified code as follows. Note we are not using literals but a `&str` returned from a third party crate.

```
fn my_func(input: &str) ->&str {
    
    let ret =
        match input {
            "a" => "Apha", // in fact, a &str from a crate
            _ => format!("'{}'", "Quoted" ).as_str(), 
        };
        
    ret
}
```

`&str` is desired because that `&str` is then pushed using `push_str()`.

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::new();
    s.push_str(my_func("a"));
    
...
```

What is your recommendation for copying the str or derefencing the temp string within the match?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't return a reference to a locally allocated `String` because the string is dropped when the function returns. There's no way to finagle your way around that. A `&str` is simply a bad match for the type of data you want to return.

The most straightforward fix is to return an owned `String`.

```
fn my_func(input: &str) -> String {
    match input {
        "a" => "Alpha".to_string(),
        _ => format!("'{}'", "Quoted" ), 
    }
}
```

Another is to return a `Cow<'_, str>`, which can hold either a borrowed or owned string depending on which you have. It's a bit fussy, but it does avoids unnecessary allocations. I only recommend this if efficiency is of utmost important; otherwise, just return `String`.

```
fn my_func(input: &str) -> Cow<'_, str> {
    match input {
        "a" => "Alpha".into(),
        _ => format!("'{}'", "Quoted" ).into(), 
    }
}
```

I'll also mention a third option -- for educational purposes, not for actual use, since it leaks memory. You can get a `'static` reference to an owned object if you [leak it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30527289/68587). Leaked memory is valid for the remainder of the program since it's never freed, and thus you can in fact get a reference to it.

```
// Warning: Do not use! Leaks memory.
fn my_func(input: &str) -> &'static str {
    match input {
        "a" => "Alpha",
        _ => Box::leak(format!("'{}'", "Quoted").into_boxed_str()), 
    }
}
```

Comment: Strings i was hoping to avoid. Cow it might be used; thanks for the pointer. Is that `_ an unused lifetime.

Comment: `'_` tells the compiler to infer the lifetime. It uses the unnamed lifetime from `input: &str` -- if I wrote `input: &'a str`, the type would be `Cow<'a, str>`. You could change it to `Cow<'static, str>` if you don't want to tie the output lifetime to the input string.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the arm with `format!().as_str()` produces an owned `String`, as soon as your function returns, the `String` is dropped and the `&str` reference would become invalid.

You can use `std::borrow::Cow` to allow a function to return both owned or borrowed strings.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, you can also change `my_func` to take a parameter that tells it where to put its result instead of returning it:

```
use std::fmt::Write;

fn my_func(output: &mut impl Write, input: &str) {
    match input {
        "a" => write!(output, "Apha").unwrap(), // in fact, a &str from a crate
        _ => write!(output, "'{}'", "Quoted" ).unwrap(), 
    };
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = String::new();
    my_func(&mut s, "a");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2c8f0b33099756033286833767ccf0b6)