# Isn't there a way to give a value to a vector without any "strings attached" / without borrowing?

Tags: rust, clone, lifetime, borrow-checker

Need help to make this work. I thought clone() would make a deep copy of my string. Then getting the literal-string of it would just be a value ... not linked to any variable?

```
fn main() {
    let mut keep_vec: Vec<&str> = vec![];

    let new_string = "New String".to_string();

    // create a new string inside an expression
    // and push it into the keep_vec
    {
        let second_string = "Second String".to_string();

        /* created this after I got ERROR:
        
        temporary value dropped while borrowed E0716 
        creates a temporary which is freed while still 
        in use Note: consider using a `let` binding to 
        create a longer lived value
         */
        
        let string_clone = second_string.clone();

        /* now getting this ERROR:
        
        `string_clone` does not live long enough E0597 
        borrowed value does not live long enough
         */
        
        keep_vec.push(string_clone.as_str());
        
    }

    keep_vec.push(&*new_string);
}
```

Here is a [link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=44b22d9c6ef7a54477844ebb5b8462fe) to the Rust Playground.

Comment: Also, it may help you to understand better your error to see what exactly causes it on [this example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=df457572abc92a9a06bf4ed5c6f2da76). It's not the same compiler error, but it's the same idea.

Comment: `&str` is not a string literal, string literals are `&'static str`, what you had have no static lifetime

Comment: You seem to think that a value such as `"hello"` and `"hello".to_string().as_str()` have the same type. But they have not: the first one is a `&'static str` that lives forever while the second is a `&'a str` that lives as long as the intermediate `String`. In your case `string_clone` has a limited lifetime and that is lifetime of `string_clone.as_str()` too.

Comment: One commenter suggested to give the `sting_clone` a longer life by putting it outside the expression. However, the issue is that the variable is being borrowed at `keep_vec.push(string_clone.as_str());` and thus, if I have many more expressions ... I would have to create many of those variable to all be there for the same reason....Isn't there a way to give a value to the vector without any "strings attached"?

Comment: I guess the problem is not necessary the LIFETIME of a string rather how to decouple the string-literal from a variable and use(burn) it in a function as a plain value with "no strings attached". Here is another [playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5a05640a18e823e031fed85fad571a89) ... I will change the Question to better reflect what I am looking for ... I hope this is ok ?!

Comment: @Robert Is this what you need? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b39d4609445fd54c448fbd0e39aae4d4

Comment: Please check this [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fdd5c474b6699924f7379c33b9589804), it will prove that it is a lifetime issue, borrowed objects can stay because the original ones are still alive

Comment: The entire confusion in the question comes (I think) from the fact that OP doesn't sufficiently understand the difference between `String` and `str`, so I would agree to mark this a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&str` is not an owned type. It is a reference to a string stored somewhere else.

`String` is the owned type that actually contains the data.

```
fn main() {
    let mut keep_vec: Vec<String> = vec![];

    let new_string = "New String".to_string();

    // create a new string inside an expression
    // and push it into the keep_vec
    {
        let second_string = "Second String".to_string();
        keep_vec.push(second_string);
    }

    keep_vec.push(new_string);
}
```

There is no need to `clone()` your strings. `to_string()` already creates a `String` which owns its content. You can simply move it into the vector.

Your problem was that `Vec<&str>` cannot hold any data, because it's a vector of references. If you want a vector that actually holds its string values, it needs to be a `Vec<String>`.

---

> getting the literal-string of it would just be a value

I think you misunderstand what a "string literal" is.

Here a quick recap, although this is already mentioned in the duplicate:

- `String` - owns its content, doesn't borrow anything. Can get created via `"bla".to_string()`.
- `&str` - reference to (part of) another string, doesn't own its content. The data it references has to outlive it.
- `&'static str` - A string literal. A reference to a string that is stored in const static memory, is immutable and valid throughout the entire program. Like `"bla"`. (Disclaimer: other things that are not string literals could also be `&'static str`; this is oversimplified to make it easier to digest for Rust beginners)

Comment: ... and as simple as that ... `Vec<String>` ... did the trick :) Thanks to @Finomnis and everyone else to help me better understand and solve this issue.

Comment: `&'static str` doesn't always mean it is a literal, you can [leak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30527289) dynamically created string into memory and represent it as `&'static str` . but yes String literals are `&'static str`

Comment: Added a disclaimer to make that clear that this is a simplified answer.